# Why am I getting session_start(): Cannot find save handler 'memcached' - session startup failed on google app engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, memcached

I configured php.ini using this following code:

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11211"
```

Can anyone please tell why am I still getting this error?

Comment: Use port not used by some other application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is your `save_path` variable.

Try this :

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11211"
```

Also check this :

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
```

are you able to connect or not?

Hope it helps!!

ref: https://www.dotdeb.org/2008/08/25/storing-your-php-sessions-using-memcached/

Comment: What file do i add this line? session.save_handler = memcached

Comment: @Supplement php.ini